# Regex (Python) to count elements in domain name

Tags: python, regex

I would like to parse an URL and count the number of "elements" in its domain name.
If I for example had an url `http://news.bbc.co.uk/foo/bar/xyzzy.html`, I would be interested in number 4 (news, bbc, co, uk).

I have always shunned regular expressions as too cryptic. I would normally do this by splitting the string between // and / and counting dots in between. This time I decided to move away from my comfort zone and boldly try some self-improvement and do this with regular expressions, counting the number of match groups.

This is what I tried:

```
pattern = r"^.*//(([^./]+\.)+)/.*$"
```

but this does not match anything. I know there is a problem somewhere there, at least in handling the final part of the domain uk/ (should be counted in but then something else than a dot should be consumed), but still breaking the match group pattern so that parsing enters the tail part.

My idea was to first consume everything until // including //. This part probably works.  Then I would start matching groups where a group is anything that is not . or /, repeat until a dot, then consume the dot, until all such groups have been consumed. These would be the match groups I am interested in.  Then consume / and deal with the rest as I am not interested in it anymore. This goes wrong.

Or is this a futile attempt to use regex somewhere where it is not suitable?

Comment: Well, yes, it is...

Comment: Oh well.. there goes my self-improvement then.

Comment: `len(s.split('/')[2].split('.'))`

Comment: Your regex fails because it *requires* the last `uk` to end with a `.` as well. Since you're not interested in what comes before and after, the anchors are not necessary; you can use `(?<=//)(([^./]+\.)+[^/]+)`. ([live on **regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/AsuaXr/1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming consistent input, you can do:

```
^[^:]+://([^/]+)
```

- `^[^:]+` matches one or more characters from start till first `:`
- `://` matches the characters literally
- `([^/]+)` the captured group contains one or more characters till next `/`

You would get e.g. `news.bbc.co.uk` using the above, then its a matter of simple `str.split('.')`.

**Note:** The obvious one, don't use Regex for this, use a proper URL parser library (e.g.`urlparse`).

**Example:**

```
In [49]: s = 'http://news.bbc.co.uk/foo/bar/xyzzy.html'

In [50]: re.search(r'^[^:]+://([^/]+)', s).group(1).split('.')
Out[50]: ['news', 'bbc', 'co', 'uk']
```

Comment: But you really should use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) instead of regex.

Comment: Thanks. I considered something like this, but I am still splitting the dots using string operations. This was more like a quest for self-learning, trying to match absolutely everything with a regexp. But not sure if it is actually possible.

Comment: `len(s.split('/')[2].split('.'))`

Comment: And urlparse is definitely the correct way of doing this. I know I am not doing this the optimal way, just trying to learn regular expressions and what they can and cannot do.

Comment: @Hannu It's not possible - at least not with a single regex. You will always have to extract the domain name first and then count the number of dots. If you absolutely have to do it with regex, you're going to need two regexes: one to extract, one to count.

Comment: @Rawing Point taken and I absolutely agree. This was just to help OP to get going. I've added a note too.

Comment: @rawing this is what my initial hunch was after tinkering with this about an hour. I just wanted to double check as I sometimes see amazing things done with regular expressions, and I have never been able to do anything but basic string matching. As I had to solve this anyway, I thought to give it a go and learn how to do this.

Comment: @Hannu Hope I've given you some primer. Let me know for anything else.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'll accept the answer to give points. The comments were definitely useful and I will stop trying today and start my quest to become the regular expressions guru maybe tomorrow.  Time for a well-deserved cup of joe.

Comment: @Hannu Regex might look cryptic at first, but once you take a good dab at it, it is simple and super fun.

Comment: I know and this is why I have been dabbling. I would assume there is a performance benefit as well in a regex compared to a set of consecutive string manipulation calls doing unoptimised, sequential searches to the string. This looked like a challenge but apparently it is a bit too much.

Comment: It's not *impossible* to use regex to completely parse the thing between `//` and `/` in a HTTP or HTTPS URL but there are several complexities which make regex not particularly suitable. You need to cope with `http://username:password@subdomain.domain.example.net:80/` and `http://12.45.67.89/` etc which of course `urlparse` already does quite nicely (and generally without regex).

Comment: @tripleee Yes. Unless the input follows a regular pattern, Regex would be too much work but definitely do-able.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex :

```
import re
pattern=r'(?:\/\/)(\w+)|(?<=\.)(\w+)'

string='http://news.bbc.co.uk/foo/bar/xyzzy.html'

result=[]
match=re.finditer(pattern,string)
for i in match:
    if i.group(1)!=None:
        result.append(i.group(1))
    elif i.group(2)!=None and i.group(2)!='html':
        result.append(i.group(2))

print(result)
```

output:

```
['news', 'bbc', 'co', 'uk']
```

But Cool thing is you can do this thing in one line:

```
import tldextract

result=tldextract.extract("http://news.bbc.co.uk/foo/bar/xyzzy.html")

print([i.split('.') for i in result])
```

output:

```
[['news'], ['bbc'], ['co', 'uk']]
```